# Add view to already existing xml viewgroup in code

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, viewgroup

I would like to be able to add a view to an already existing xml layout in code:

```
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.common_list);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setText("sample text");
        ll.addView(tv);

        setContentView(ll);
```

When creating a new LinearLayout in code it works, but when using a Resource like in the code above it doesn’t.

common_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Quick List"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which error gives you in the logcat?

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidABC/com.example.androidABC.Common_ActivityList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 14:59:57.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
09-01 14:59:57.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
09-01 14:59:57.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use LayoutInflater

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.common_list)
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("sample text");
ll.addView(tv);

setContentView(ll);
```

If this won't work, please add error from Logcat.

Also, you should change properties from android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content" in yout LinearLayout in common_list.xml and also do the same thing to your TextView in common_list.xml

Why? Because your layout is horizontal-oriented and it fills whole screen space. Your TextEdit fills as much space as your layout does (so in this case it's whole screen space). Now, when you add another TextView it is adding properly - to right of your first TextEdit, so it's like out of screen. To understand exactly what happens:

```
-----------------
||-------------||---------------
||| TextViev1 ||||addedTextView|
||-------------||---------------
||             ||
||             ||
||             ||
||             ||
||             ||
||LinearLayout ||
||-------------||
|    screen     |
----------------
```

I also had this problem many times. Usually if you add View to layout and you don't see it (and you get no errors) problem is with width/heigth or position (ex. when you use RelativeLayout).

Comment: Now it opens the activity but it doesn’t show the created TextView. Here is the code I used: `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.common_list, null);

  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     tv.setText("sample text");
     ll.addView(tv);
     
     setContentView(ll); `

Comment: Attach your common_list.xml please.

Comment: I added it to the problem description

Comment: try to change from android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content" in yout LinearLayout in common_list.xml and also do the same thing to your TextView in common_list.xml

Comment: Wow, thanks. Now the question is why? Is it because LayoutInflater has no root ViewGroup? Would be nice if you could edit your example and add an explanation to it to help other too. I spend today so many hours on this problem. Thanks again, you are my hero :)

Comment: I've added explanation :) Feel free to ask if something still isn't clear